# Matrix of orthogonal reflection in standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $\mathbb{C}^n$)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L$ be a subspace of euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ (hermitian space $\mathbb{C}^n$) is given by its basis $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_m$.

Show that matrix $A$ (in standard basis) of operator of orthogonal reflection respect to subspace $L^{\perp}$ is given by $$A=E-2W(W^*W)^{-1}W^*,$$ where $W$ is the $n\times m$ matrix, whose columns are the coordinates of vectors $e_1,e_2,\dots e_m$.

Actually my question is not about the proof of this because I proved it by myself but about the expression $A=E-2W(W^*W)^{-1}W^*$.

Since $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ then $A=E-2WW^{-1}(W^*)^{-1}W^*=E-2E=-E$. So am I right that $A=-E$? Or maybe I am misunderstanding something?

Would be thankful for useful answer!

Comment: What is $W^{-1}$ in case of a matrix $W$ of rank $\min(m,n)=m<n$... ?!

Comment: @dan_fulea, yeah you are right if $m<n$ then matrix $M$ is not a square matrix and we cannot define $M^{-1}$. But how do we know that $(W^*W)^{-1}$ exists? I see that the matrix $W^*W$ is the square matrix. But why the inverse of it exists?

Comment: @dan_fulea, yeah it does exists because it is the Gram matrix of linearly independent vectors $e_1,\dots,e_m$.

Comment: Yes, it is an $m\times m$ matrix.

Comment: @dan_fulea, thanks a lot for your answer! It helped me a lot! :) Actually my question was a stupid one :)

Comment: It is ok, please always ask, different people have different types of errors, and different views. I also have my blind moments and systematic errors. Life is too short to not ask...

Comment: @dan_fulea, thanks a lot for such nice words! One more time thanks for help!